# Download image from URL keeping exif data

Tags: java

I'm trying to download an image with exif data from URL to my pc, the problem is that exif data is gone after the image has been downloaded.

here's the code i use

```
public static void downloadImage(String str) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Goldmantelziesel.jpg");
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
            File file = new File("F:\\Photos\\ww123\\"+str+".jpg");
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", file);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are reading and saving the image. That's why metadata is missing.

Comment: If you want to keep the metadata, you can open a connection from the URL, read the whole stream and save it as is.